# Finishing a triangle with loops

Tags: java, for-loop, geometry

I'm trying to make a right sided triangle that looked like this in Java with loops:

```
     +
    /|
   / |
  /  |
 /   |
+----+
```

The program needed the args as an int to determine the size of each of the triangle's sides. Now this is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            for (int j = x; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("/");
        }

    System.out.print("+");
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.print("+");
}
```

And the result so far is this

```
     /
    /
   /
  /
 +---+
```

So how should I approach this? I tried some combination of for loops, but so far it often prints out a mangled mess of a shape rather than an actual triangle.

Comment: since `/` and `|` are in the same line, you're simply missing print the `|` in the same statement, but with spaces in between. Figure out how many spaces you need and add them between your `/` and `|`.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there: in the nested loop where you print `'/'`, replace `println` with `print`. Add a second loop that prints `x-j` spaces, then print `|`. Finally, add a statement to print `+` before entering the first loop. That would be it!

To optimize your code, consider writing a helper method:

```
void printN(String str, int numTimes) {
    // Prints numTimes copies of str
}
```

This way you would be able to "flod" several loops into a single call of `printN`. For example,

```
for (int j = x; j >= i; j--) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

would become

```
printN(" ", x-i);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct amount of spaces for your pipe symbol you need to add one more for loop.

Within this for loop you are going to set the iteration counter equal to your outside loop iteration counter. Then within the for loop you are going to use a String Builder. On each loop you will add a space to the string builder. Then, once the final space has been added you will put the / in the spaces and the | on the end.

That is the most I will give for an obvious school question. The only way to learn is to do friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for (int j = x+1; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("+");
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = x; j >= i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("I");
    }

    System.out.print("+");
    for (int j = 0; j < x+1; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.print("+");
}
```

Comment: I do not get why somebody downgraded this. It works fine. At least put a comment

Comment: Not my downvote, but how about a little explanation? Your answer is pretty opaque. My sense is that Doh isn't looking for a handout - he's interested in being enlightened.

Comment: I see! Thanks for feedback. When I finished the code and wanted to copy and explain, I noticed others mentioned that he had to simply use print for printing / so I thought that my code would be complementary. Again, Michael I appreciate your feedback.